# ReactJS Fetch User Data from API and add to table

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm using `react hooks` to fetch data from an API and I want to display it in a table. Seemingly very simple, but I'm missing something. **The problem is that no data is being rendered in the `<table>`.**

Also, I want to know if I'm even remotely on the right track in how this should all be done. Please correct me if I'm heading in the wrong direction in terms of best practices.

**./app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/Header';
import UserList from './components/UserList';

export default function App() {  

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={UserList} />
            </Switch>
            {/* <Sidebar /> */}
        </BrowserRouter>            
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**./helpers/FetchData/FetchData.js**

```
import React from 'react';


export const useFetch = (url, options) => {
    const [response, setResponse] = React.useState({});
    const [error, setError] = React.useState({});
    React.useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const res = await fetch(url, options);
          const json = await res.json();
          setResponse(json);
        } catch (error) {
          setError(error);
        }
      };
      fetchData();
    }, []);
    return { response, error };
};
```

**./components/UserList/UserList.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useFetch } from '../../helpers/FetchData';

export default function UserList() {
    const res = useFetch('https://randomuser.me/api', {});

    if(!res.response.results) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    const data = res.response.results;
    console.log(data);

    return (
        <table className="table table-striped table-dark">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">City</th>
            <th scope="col">State</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {data && data.map(row => {
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" key={row.id}>{row.id}</th>
                    <td>{row.name.first}}</td>
                    <td>{row.name.last}</td>
                    <td>{row.location.city}</td>
                    <td>{row.location.state}</td>
                </tr>
            })}    
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is the result of the `console.log(data)` statement in the UserList component, so I know there is data getting returned:

[image]

Comment: Calling `useEffect` in `App` looks redundant btw, log out the result of `useFetch` immediately after calling it and share an example of the result? The only thing stopping this is the `!res.response.results` gate, we know you will always have `res.response` so the unknown is what comes back from the server. If, for example, it's an JSON array then you just need to change the gate to `!res.results.length` and set the default value to `[]` as opposed to `{}`

Comment: @James - good catch. I actually had fixed the redundant call in my code, but neglected to change my question before posting. I just updated it to remove that so it won't cause confusion.

Comment: @James - also added a screenshot of the data coming back, which I'm logging after the gate you mentioned, so I know it's getting past the gate. I can also console.log(row.id.value) inside of the map function and it logs the ID, so it's seems to be working at that point as well.

Comment: `row.id` is an object according to your log. Objects are not valid as a React child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing any table rows is because your `data.map` call is not returning anything.  The way you've defined it, it needs to include a `return` call, like this:

```
{data && data.map(row => {
        return (
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" key={row.id}>{row.id}</th>
                <td>{row.name.first}}</td>
                <td>{row.name.last}</td>
                <td>{row.location.city}</td>
                <td>{row.location.state}</td>
            </tr>
         );
 })}
```

As currently defined in your code, it creates the `tr` in the map function, but does not return it.

Comment: Haha beat me to it, you can leverage the default return value with arrow functions though (see my answer)

Comment: You're welcome.  The only reason I picked up on it right away is because I've done the same more times than I can count!